# Clarification on .otf font format

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I've been supplied an OTF font from a client and not following the web font trends for a while now in terms of support, if I remember correctly, the pattern used for cross browser support for web fonts would look like this:

```
 @font-face {

    font-family: 'AvalonBook';

    src: url('Avalon-Book-webfont.eot');

    src: url('Avalon-Book-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),

         url('Avalon-Book-webfont.woff') format('woff'),

         url('Avalon-Book-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),

         url('Avalon-Book-webfont.svg#AvalonBook') format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;

    font-style: normal;

}
```

Probably because I've been so used to copying and pasting the above code and modifying it to my needs, I haven't got the chance to actually understand the reasons behind this pattern.

This begs the question, is OTF even supported in the browsers? What browsers and versions? Also why is it not in the above @font-face declaration if it is supported?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK Modern browsers all do support OTF, yes. And if it isn't in the above declaration you will just have to add it in. `url('Avalon-Book-webfont.otf') format('opentype');` Don't use svg though. SVG fonts were a mistake.

Comment: Oh, a quick Google turns up that OTF and TTF fonts are only usable in IE if their "installable" bit is set. So you may have to experiment. If it doesn't work, use fontsquirrel or something to create an EOT file from the OTF.